# Including special characters in column names in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there in BigQuery a way to include special characters (such as %, white space, periods etc) in column names, resp. can you somehow escape special characters?
In my case it would come in handy when col names would be more readable for example when exporting reports.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical

Comment: Thanks, I'll check whether this works when switching to legacy SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No, the rules for field names (and aliases) in BigQuery [are](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names):

> A column name must contain only letters (a-z, A-Z), numbers (0-9), or
> underscores (_), and it must start with a letter or underscore. The
> maximum column name length is 300 characters. A column name cannot use
> any of the following prefixes: _TABLE_, _FILE_, _PARTITION_.
> Duplicate column names are not allowed even if the case differs. For example, a column named Column1 is considered identical
> to a column named column1.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I was hoping for some kind of workaround. Looks like I might have to live with this.